# How to conditionally render a React component based on a specific viewport width?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React to build a responsive web application, and I have a component that should only be displayed on screens with a certain viewport width. How do I conditionally render this component based on the current viewport width?

I have tried to read the documentation, however it was really messy and confusing for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to conditionally render a React component based on the viewport width, you can use a combination of the window.innerWidth property and the window.addEventListener method to listen for the resize event. By doing so, you can manage the state of your component to render or hide it based on the current window size.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ResponsiveComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(window.innerWidth >= 768);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsVisible(window.innerWidth >= 768);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isVisible && (
        <div>
          <p>This component is only visible when the viewport width is 768px or larger.</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ResponsiveComponent;
```

Comment: I think that will cause a flashing effect when you set `state` out of the gate like that